How can I count the days (and impact) of an event when it overlaps months- Excel



Name
Name
Part
Capacity
Impact
Start
End
Weeks
Impact (Week)
Impact (PerDay)




Jane
Jane

4.45
4
19 Jul 24
25 Jul 24
1
4
0.6


Jewel
Jewel
T1
5.2
3
21 Jul 24
23 Jul 24
0.4

1


Pluto
Pluto

7.7
7.7
30 Jul 24
6 Aug 24
1.1
7
0.96


Garnet
Garnet

5
0.8
1 Aug 24
25 Aug 24
3.6
0.2
0.03


Sabine
Sabine

11
3
3 Aug
15 Aug 24
1.9
1.6
0.2


Daisy
Daisy

3.5
0.2
10 Aug 24
1 Sep 24
3.1
0.06
0.01


Queenie
Queenie
P2
4
2
4 Sep 24
15 Sep 24
1.7
1.2
0.2


Jane
Jane

4.45
0.4
20 Jul 24
12 Aug 24
2
0.2
0.03


Pluto
Pluto

7.7
3
5 Aug 24
10 Sep 24
5.1
0.6
0.08



How can I create a formula that will sum the impact of an event when I can have multiple events for a variable, and the dates often start and end across two or more months? Basically need to be able to sum the impact for 'Jane' in June, July... etc that will count all entries that have an impact during the calendar month.
I have tried two Excel formulas that have not worked for me:
=SUMIFS(N2:N14,B2:B14,A28,G2:G14,“>”&B26,H2:H14,“<”&C26)
This just returned zero
=LET(sday,B26,eday,C26,proj,A27,arr,FILTER(B2:E14,A2:A14=proj),SUM(BYROW(arr,LAMBDA(arrb,DAYS(MIN(eday,INDEX(arrb,,2)),MAX(0,sday,INDEX(arrb,,1)))*INDEX(arrb,,4)))))
This returned the CALC error
So results would look like:
| Name | Jul 24 | Aug 24 | Sep 24 |
| Jane | 4.2 | 0.2 | 0 |
| Pluto | 1.92 | 5.74 | 0 |
Results I think

I'm confused. Your posted data is missing the date column as posted in the image, yet your formula seems to reference the data as posted in the table data, not the image.

Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel are different products, have different feature sets, and will most likely require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states "Do NOT use with [excel]" and the [excel] tag description explicitly states "Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]." Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Please resolve the discrepancies between your screenshot and your text data; and also indicate your expected results from the posted data.

Using SUMPRODUCT for Conditional Logic
you can try to use this approach to get the total impact column
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A = "Jane") * (F2:F <= DATE(2024,7,31)) * (G2:G >= DATE(2024,7,1)) * (E2:E) * 
  (IF(G2:G > DATE(2024,7,31), DATE(2024,7,31), G2:G) - IF(F2:F < DATE(2024,7,1), DATE(2024,7,1), F2:F) + 1) / (G2:G - F2:F + 1)
)

formula checks if an event starts on or before the end of July (F2:F <= DATE(2024,7,31)) and ends on or after the start of July (G2:G >= DATE(2024,7,1)), ensuring that only events overlapping with July are considered.
To calculate the portion relevant to July, I use DAYS in JULY / TOTAL DAYS of EVENT.
Sample output

Reference

SUMPRODUCT

Note: Please review the result to confirm if it meets your expectations. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly.

btw I used Gsheet formula for this approach

SUMIFS() should work. Try-
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,K2,E:E,">="&L2,F:F,"<="&M2)



Hi, I tried this formula but it doesn't count the second entry e.g. row 9 Jane. L4 only contains the July sum for the first Jane entry (row 2) and not the second (row 9) which covers part of July and August. Is there any way to include this second entry?

@CarysStockton I believe you need reverse logic then. Try =SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,K2,E:E,"<="&M2,F:F,">="&L2). It will give  4.4 as result.

But that then counts the August impact- 4.2 for July and 0.2 for August as the second Jane entry is into August

following this thread @CarysStockton, could you explain why the result is 4.2? The first entry for Jane in the 'Impact' column is 4, and the second is 0.4

It is 4.2 as the second entry of 0.4 is across July and August, so only a portion of the 0.4 (impact) falls into July- it runs from 20 July to 12 August so Jane would see a 4.2 impact in July total and 0.2 in August  @Patsytalk

Interpreting the data according to the second formula (which worked fine under Google Sheets also),



Project
Start
End
Weeks
Impact (Week)




Jane
7/19/24
7/25/24
1
4


Jewel
7/21/24
7/23/24
0.4



Pluto
7/30/24
8/6/24
1.1
7


Garnet
8/1/24
8/25/24
3.6
0.2


Sabine
8/3/24
8/15/24
1.9
1.6


Daisy
8/10/24
9/1/24
3.1
0.06


Queenie
9/4/24
9/15/24
1.7
1.2


Jane
7/20/24
8/12/24
2
0.2


Pluto
8/5/24
9/10/24
5.1
0.6



Here's the result for June-July:

Get impact per day
multiply by number of days within period and sum

=LET(
    sday, B26,
    eday, C26,
    proj, A27,
    arr, FILTER(B2:E14, A2:A14 = proj),
    SUM(
        BYROW(
            arr,
            LAMBDA(arrb,
                MAX(
                    DAYS(
                        MIN(eday, INDEX(arrb, , 2)),
                        MAX(sday, INDEX(arrb, , 1))
                    ) + 1,
                    0
                ) * INDEX(arrb, , 4) / 7
            )
        )
    )
)



Hi thank you. I tried this method but it gives 3.7 for the impact of Jane, when it should be 4+0.1 for the impact in July? Is that a calculation error or something else?

Just following this thread, why isn't the result 4 + 0.2 (second entry for Jane has impact of 0.4, half of which is in July)?

I am not sure either @TomSharpe as I can't work out why it isn't adding the portion of the 0.2 (second Jane entry) that also falls into July. Is it maybe getting stuck after reading the first Jane entry it finds? But then I am unsure why it gives 3.7 instead of 4 for July

@CarysStockton, thanks for testing. I have corrected the number of days calculation; and I have also added steps showing how I'm calculating. I divide the value for impact for week by 7 and then multiply by number of days. Please correct if that's wrong.

@TomSharpe, thanks for checking. I've corrected the days calc. I divide the value for impact for week by 7 and then multiply by number of days. Please correct if that's wrong.

I think I have managed it! will add the picture to the post thank you

@CarysStockton, very good! Also, please let me know if the way I calculated was not what you expected.
